# How to get properties through loop from a REST JSON response using Httpfull in PHP and how to show in grid

Tags: php, web-services, web, exchangewebservices

As in the URL, I don't want to give a limit, I want to show in loop
[0]. I don't want to give [0] or [1] etc. I want to do it in a loop.

```
 http://buildout.com/api/v1/d7d8b6a8cbd23c1f69e3a327b32c8217d6bea635/properties.json?limit=2

 <?php    
     $url='my url';
     $res = \Httpful\Request::get($url)->expectsJson()->send();
     $data = json_decode($res,true);
     $name1 =  $data['properties'][0]['broker_id'];  // I WANT LOOP HERE INSTED OF [0]
     echo $city1;  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the response data dynamically to get each datum without specifying the index as follows:

```php
foreach ($data['properties'] as $key=>$val) {       
    var_dump($key);
}
```

The `$key` can be:

- First `$data['properties'][0];`
- Next  `$data['properties'][1];`
- and so on...

Comment: i need loop here [0] don't want to give limit

Comment: @MohammadArifMaseed yes the answer above will give you the dynamic loop from the result you want, as the `$key` will represent the data with index in each loop. Or you can do loop by `for ($idx = 0; $idx < sizeof($data['properties']); $idx++)` if you want

Comment: echo  $property['photos'] '<a href="#"><img src="'.$property['url']. '" style="height:200px; width:200px; align:center; float:left;margin-right:50px;"></a>';